# Select apenas se o ID estiver em 2 tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, select

Tenho 2 tabelas em Mysql, **INSCRICAO1** e **INSCRICAO2**. Ambas tem um campo chamado **COD** que recebe um codigo do usuário.

A **INSCRICAO1** guarda as informações pessoais do usuário
A **INSCRICAO2** guarda as informações do carro do usuário

Preciso dar um select na **INSCRICAO1** apenas dos usuários que possuem carros, ou seja, que estão presentes também na tabela **INSCRICAO2**.

Como fazer, tentei com LEFT JOIN, mas deu erro.

Comment: Na verdade você descreveu o comportamento do `INNER JOIN`. Mas com o select em si, só poderemos ajudar se você compartilhar sua tentativa. A forma de fazer depende do modelo de dados, não há informações suficientes para dar uma resposta precisa, estou marcando como unclear.

Comment: A resposta era essa, INNER JOIN, valeu! De qualquer forma vou melhorar a pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Faça assim:

```
SELECT * FROM  inscricao1 INNER JOIN inscricao2 ON inscricao1.cod = inscricao2.cod
```

Answer (score 0):

Pensei em uma forma diferente:

```
   SELECT a.cod, b.cod FROM inscricao1 as a, inscricao2 as b WHERE a.cod = b.cod;
```

Simples assim usando alias.